# How to transpile between languages with different scoping rules?

Tags: python, transpilers

Suppose I have a block scoped language, in this case represented

```js
let b=2;

function a() {
    b+=1;
    let c;
    while (c>b) {
        let c;
        c-=1;
        b-=c;
    }
}
```

How can I transpile this into something like python where variables are function scoped?

Ideally I'd want to output something vaguely readable and not mangle the variable names too much.

Note that some variables now alias, like `c`, some need their scope expanded like `b` and some reduced like `c`. Ideally I'd have some generic system that could handle arbitrary scopes no matter what the rules of the source language are.

Both languages are dynamically typed.

Comment: Lexically scoped languages cannot emulate dynamically scoped languages.

Comment: @Aster they surely can, at a price of replacing every potentially dynamically scoped variable reference with a global hash table lookup.

Answer (score 8):

When TypeScript needs variable names to not conflict, it suffixes variables of otherwise identical names with `_1`, `_2`, etc. You could have `c_1` and `c_2` in your example code above.

For global variables, Python at least has the keywords `nonlocal` and `global`. I've seen Python code before like

```py
def frobnicate():
  global foo
  global bar
  global baz
  global qux
  # ... it went on for a while.
```

Though I imagine that's not common in idiomatic code.

So, your example in the question would become:

```py
b = 2
def a():
  global b
  b = b + 1
  c_1 = None # Since it starts as `undefined` in the JS, and `None` is arguably
             # the best translation of that
  while c_1 > b:
    c_2 = None
    c_2 = c_2 - 1
    b = b - c_2
```

Comment: FYI you can do `global foo, bar, baz, qux` all on one line if you wanted to. It would also apply to the whole scope so the extra `global b` is indeed unnecessary.

Comment: +1 for renaming, and I think `nonlocal` might be more appropriate here instead of `global`.

Comment: Note that `b = b+1` and `b += 1` are not equivalent in python. In fact you wouldn't need `global b` if you only updated `b` using `+=` and never `=`.

Comment: @Stef To be honest, I couldn’t remember whether Python even had `+=` to begin with. Like I said, I don’t Python much.

Comment: @Bbrk24 It does. But `b += 1` is not a synonym for `b = b + 1`. When you do `b = ...` you're binding a value to a local name `b`, regardless of whether there is already something else named `b`. But when you do `b += ...`, you're updating the object bound to the already-existing name `b`, which might be less local.

Comment: Actually, you would still need `global b` if you only updated `b` using `+=`.
`b = 2
def a():
    b += 1` 
still raises `UnboundLocalError` when `a` is called.

Answer (score 5):

The scope of a variable can be expanded by moving its declaration further out; to translate between block-scoped and function-scoped variables, you need to make sure the declaration is at the top of the function. This may mean that two variables which had the same name in the source program may end up having the same scope, and one must be renamed. Unfortunately there is no way around this, so even if you don't want to "mangle the variable names too much" you will still have to mangle them slightly. It's up to you what kind of mangling you decide to do; I like to append numbers starting from 2, so `c`, `c2`, `c3` and so on:

```javascript
function a() {
    let c, c2;
    // ...
}
```

The other thing you need to take care of is when the source and target languages have different rules for reassigning non-local variables. Some languages (e.g. Javascript) just allow this, others (e.g. Python) require you to declare which non-local variables as `global` or `nonlocal` if you want to reassign them, while others still (e.g. Java) may outright forbid reassigning captured variables even when the assignment occurs locally.

To get around this, you can wrap the variable in a mutable container:

```javascript
let b = {value: 2};

function a() {
    b.value += 1;
    // ...
}
```

This works by replacing variable accesses with field accesses, and variable assignments with field assignments. Most imperative languages support both in some way.